# neet to create php desktop application

Tags: php, desktop-application

i want to create php intranet chat application, i mean desktop application.

is it possible? if possible means please tell how to do? Refer any tutorial link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason to use php? Why not use technologies that are much more convenient for such task?

Comment: Check out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXt8erPLf4o. This video shows you how to convert your PHP scripts to run on windows.

Answer (score 1):

There is another one called PHP-Qt http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-qt/

You can write Qt application using PHP language.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this:

http://winbinder.org/index.php

form the FAQs:

> **What is WinBinder?** A. WinBinder is a new open source extension that
>   allows PHP programmers to easily build native Windows applications.
>
> **Why should I use WinBinder?** A. WinBinder encapsulates a great deal of
>   the complexity of the Windows API, so applications can be developed
>   quickly and easily. Since PHP is a scripting language you are not
>   required to compile anything, just code and run. Click [here](http://winbinder.org/why.php) for a
>   more detailed explanation.
>
> **How much does it cost?** A. Nothing. WinBinder is released as open source, meaning it is completely free for home or commercial use. Its
>   source code is also freely available and is included in the
>   distribution files.

This extension package is less than 5 MB to download.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use PHP as a desktop application, maybe it can help you:

[PHP-GTK](http://gtk.php.net/)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the wrong language to start with.

Try this though if your really keen: [GTK-PHP](http://gtk.php.net)

Answer (score 0):

PHP was designed for creating dynamic webpages and it does that very well.

I am not saying that PHP should not be used be used for desktop applications but just that the tools like PHP-GTK and WinBinder are not mature enough for serious application development.

In the current time, its better to stick to other languages, which are better suited for desktop application development. PHP might come into mainstream desktop application development in future versions but we'll have wait for that.